# On the contragredient representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $\pi$ be a representation of group $G$.Then its contragredient representation $\pi^{\vee}$ is defined by $\pi^{\vee}(g)=^{t}\pi(g^{-1})$. (here $^t$ means the transpose)

But I heard that it is dual to the original representation $\pi$. So I think that if $\pi$ is unitary, then $\pi \otimes \pi^{\vee}=Id$, the identity representation on $V$.

But it seems not hold because the transpose action on the definition of contragredient representation.

What's wrong in my above reasoning?

Comment: [Dual representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_representation) and contragredient representation are the same things. "Dual" does not necessarily mean "dual" in your sense, but refers to the dual vector space.

Comment: Good point made by @Dietrich Burde, OP needs to sort out what he means by the $\,^{t}$

Comment: Sorry, there is some typo in my notation. Not composition but we should take the tensor product. $^t$ means a transpose.